# Limit as radius approaches 0 of double integral bounded by unit circle

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus

**Problem**:

Let $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function such as $f(0) = 0$, compute

$$\lim_{r\to 0^{+}} \iint_{x^2 + y^2 \leq r^2} {3 \over 2\pi r^3} f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) dx$$

**Progress**:

I figure the solution to this is likely 0 because the domain is approaching 0, so intuitively there cannot by any resulting volume.  I got as far as converting the problem into polar coordinates, which makes it look much cleaner, but I was unsure how to integrate the product of $f(\rho)\rho  d\rho$.  Integration by parts did not give a useful result.  Could someone please demonstrate how to obtain that integral, or present another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to get an answer by the L’Hopital’s rule.
\begin{align}
&\quad \lim_{r\to0^+}\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq r^2} \frac{3}{2\pi r^3} f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\, dxdy \\&=\lim_{r\to0^+}\int_0^r\int_{\partial B(0,\rho)}  \frac{3}{2\pi r^3} f\left(\rho\right)\,dS d\rho\\&= \lim_{r\to0^+}\int_0^r \frac{3\rho f(\rho)}{r^3}\,d\rho\\&=\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{\int_0^r 3\rho f(\rho)\,d\rho}{r^3}\\&=\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{3rf(r)}{3r^2}\\&=\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{f(r)}{r}\\&=f’(0).
\end{align}
The last equal is according to the definition of derivative.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.  My only question is what happens to the $\rho$ between the 4th and 5th steps? I understand that if we just had $f(\rho)$ the integral would transform into $f(r)$ after being derived through l'hopital, but the extra $\rho$ seems to mess that up.  How are we able to eliminate that?

Comment: You can look $\rho f(\rho)$ as a new function, say $g(\rho)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{R\to 0^{+}} \iint_{x^2 + y^2 \leq R^2} {3 \over 2\pi r^{3}} f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) dxdy
=\lim_{R\to 0^{+}} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R} {3 \over 2\pi r^3}r^{2} f(r) drd\theta
=\lim_{R\to 0^{+}} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R} {3 \over 2\pi r} f(r) drd\theta$

integrating in $\theta$ the $2\pi$ cancels and you have

$\lim_{R\to 0^{+}} 3\int_{0}^{R} \frac{1}{r} f(r) dr$.  If we analize its absolute value,

$|\int_{0}^{R} \frac{1}{r} f(r) dr| \leq \int_{0}^{R} |\frac{1}{r} f(r) |dr =\int_{0}^{R} \frac{1}{r} |f(r)| dr\leq \int_{0}^{R} \frac{1}{r} Mr dr =MR\to0$ (if $R\to0$), where in the last inequality I used the fact that if $f$ is a diferenciable function such that $f(0)=0$ then $f(x)=f'(0)x+o_{2}$, so if $x$ is little then $|f(x)|\leq Mx$.